# disable backspace to prevent default value of input to be erased JQUERY

Tags: jquery, keycode

I have a registration form and there has an input for cellphone number, i set a default value "+63" on it when it is clicked. Now i want to disable backspace when it detected +63 value of input

```
$('#contact').click(function(){
    var code = "+63";
    $('#contact').val(code);
});    

$('#contact').on('change keydown', function(e){
        //codes here

});
```

Comment: I suggest to have a different approach here. Here's why: there are many ways to remove text from a textbox (ctrl x, right mouse button, etc). So my suggestion if +63 is always the prefix, set label with this text just before the textbox and use js to concatenate this value to the label text... just an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `preventDefault()` when your `input` value is `+63`

```js
$('#contact').click(function(){
    var code = "+63";
    $('#contact').val(code);
});    

$('#contact').on('change keydown', function(e){
        if( ($('#contact').val() == "+63") && e.which==8){
         e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='contact'>
```